# Iterate through python dictionary and appending key component in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary, `tempDict`

```
{('M1', 'P1'): 6.0,
 ('M1', 'P2'): 10.0,
 ('M1', 'P3'): 4.0,
 ('M2', 'P1'): 7.0,
 ('M2', 'P2'): 9.0,
 ('M2', 'P3'): 5.0}
```

I am doing some operations over this dictionary and taking the some key components to a list. Say I have `l1 = [], l2 = []`.

Suppose minimum value is 4 the I find that `jobsR as ('M1', 'P3')`.I would like to remove the all the keys where 'P3' appears from the tempDict.

I will be finding the minimum value from this dictionary iteratively and will drop corresponding keys. As the keys are ordered pairs, if the departed key element has 1st component `M1` then I shall take the 2nd component in list `l1` else in `l2`. I shall continue until the dictionary becomes empty. My code is,

```
while bool(tempDict):
    try:
        l1 = []
        l2 = []
        valMin = min(tempDict.values())
        jobsR = [key for key in tempDict if tempDict[key] == valMin]
        for (x, y) in jobsR:
            if x == 'M1':
                l1.append(y)
            else:
                l2.append(y)
        remove_list = []
        for key, value in tempDict.items():
            if jobsR[0][1] in key[1]:
                remove_list.append(key)
        for item in remove_list:
            tempDict.pop(item)
    except KeyError:
        print('The dictionary has no item now...')
        break
```

Expected output:

`l1 = [P3, P1] and l2 = [P2]`

**Code_Updated**

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
while bool(tempDict):
    valMin = min(tempDict.values())
    jobsR = [key for key in tempDict if tempDict[key] == valMin]
    remove_list = []
    for key, value in tempDict.items():
        if jobsR[0][1] in key[1]:
            remove_list.append(key)
    for item in remove_list:
        tempDict.pop(item)
    for x in jobsR:
        #print(x[0])
        if x[0] == 'M1':
            l1.append(item[1])
        else:
            l2.append(item[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

lists l1 and l2 are set into [ ] in every cycle of the while loop. Declare l1 and l2 outside of the while loop to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `l1` and `l2` out of the while loop and pop keys as you go:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
while tempDict:
    min_val = min(tempDict.values())
    jobsR = [k for k,v in tempDict.items() if v==min_val][0]
    if jobsR[0] == 'M1':
        l1.append(jobsR[1])
    else:
        l2.append(jobsR[1])
    for k in tempDict:
        if k[1]==jobsR[1]]:
            tempDict.pop(k)
```

Output:

```
# l1 = ['P3', 'P1']
# l2 = ['P2']
```

Note: This assumes each minimum value has a unique key.